# how to center the button on the screen resizeing?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```css
.codrops-top {
        line-height: 30px;
        font-size: 13px;
        background: #fff;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
        text-transform: uppercase;
        z-index: 9999;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        font-family: Cambria, Georgia, serif;
        box-shadow: 1px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        font-weight: 900;
    }
    .codrops-top a {
        padding: 0px 10px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        color: #333;
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .codrops-top a:hover {
        color:#12836d;
        cursor:pointer;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .codrops-top span.right{
        float: right;
        
    }
    .codrops-top a{
        color:black;
    }
    .fa{
        padding:0 5px;
    }
    .codrops-top span a.btn {
        padding: 9px 38px;
        line-height: 20px;
    }
    .codrops-top span a.btn-primary {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #5bbc2e;
        border-color: #5bbc2e;
    }
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
        .codrops-top{
            text-align: center;
        }
        .codrops-top span.right{
            text-align: center;
            float:none;

        }
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 1338px){
.largeScreen {width:100%;text-align:center;}
.largeScreen span {display:inline-block;}
.hide{
    display: none;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="codrops-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 hide">
                        <a href="">
                            <strong>Your Tech Friend </strong><span><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i></span>+91-8510-808-808
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div style="text-align:center;" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 hide">
                        <a href="">
                            <strong><span><i class="fa fa-book"></i></span>Blog</strong>
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                            <strong><span><i class="fa fa-trophy"></i></span>Career</strong>
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                            <strong><span><i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i></span>Site Map</strong>
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                            <strong><span><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i></span>Request a Quote</strong>
                        </a>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 largeScreen">
                        <span class="right">
                            <a href="">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Client Area</a>
                            </a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

now i want the client area button in the center on size of 1338px screen and all the things should be hidden only the button should be in the center.
i have tried it but the button is not coming in center it is coming on the left side.

Comment: Do you want center align the button for 1338px only or for all the screen.

Comment: @Ezhil-UIDeveloper which part u have edited?

Comment: i worked on css  part .

Answer (score 0):

```css
.codrops-top {
        line-height: 30px;
        font-size: 13px;
        background: #fff;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
        text-transform: uppercase;
        z-index: 9999;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        font-family: Cambria, Georgia, serif;
        box-shadow: 1px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        font-weight: 900;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .codrops-top a {
        padding: 0px 10px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        color: #333;
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .codrops-top a:hover {
        color:#12836d;
        cursor:pointer;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .codrops-top a{
        color:black;
    }
    .fa{
        padding:0 5px;
    }
    .codrops-top span a.btn {
        padding: 9px 38px;
        line-height: 20px;
    }
    .codrops-top span a.btn-primary {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #5bbc2e;
        border-color: #5bbc2e;
    }
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
        .codrops-top{
            text-align: center;
        }
        .codrops-top span.right{
            text-align: center;
            float:none;

        }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1338px){
        #hide{
           
        }
        .codrops-top{
           text-align: center;
           float:right;
       }
   }
```

```html
<div class="codrops-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div id="hide" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                        <a href="">
                            <strong>Your Tech Friend </strong><span><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i></span>+91-8510-808-808
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="hide" style="text-align:center;" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <a href="">
                            <strong><span><i class="fa fa-book"></i></span>Blog</strong>
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                            <strong><span><i class="fa fa-trophy"></i></span>Career</strong>
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                            <strong><span><i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i></span>Site Map</strong>
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                            <strong><span><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i></span>Request a Quote</strong>
                        </a>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                        <span class="right">
                            <a href="">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Client Area</a>
                            </a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @harsh use this: https://jsfiddle.net/ru2zdqm0/  Copy the updated CSS from this link and use it.

Comment: thank you for your time my friend but when i use the display:none in the #hide id the client area section is going on the left. And i want to hide all things except client area button when i resize my screen to 1338px or less.

Comment: So below 1338px screen size you want to hide all the content except client area button and same time the button should be in center of the screen ?

Comment: ya after the 1338px the client area should be in the center for all the screens

Comment: in which section have you edited?and it will show all the text when its in the original size?

Comment: i just added display:none for #hide at media query css. Which screen size you are checking.

Comment: on the full screen view, all the text should be displayed and when i resize the screen to 1338px and less all the text should not be there except the client area button. I have tried the display none it is working but the client area button is going to the left not in the center

Comment: check your monitor screen size, i think your full screen size is above 1338px so it's shows all content.

Comment: ya i want to show all my content after 1338px and before 1338px less than 1338px size only button should be displayed

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have included bootstrap to your code.

```
<style> 
    @media screen and (min-width: 1338px){
        .largeScreen {width:100%;text-align:center;}
        .largeScreen span {display:inline-block;}
        .hide {display:none;}
    }
</style>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 largeScreen">
    <span>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Client Area</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

- Avoid using same id's multiple times in your code. I can see
  id="hide" twice. You can use class="hide" instead.
- I would suggest renaming the hide class if you want to hide the elements only above 1338px as the bootstrap hide class hides the contents at all resolutions.
- You missed mentioning display:none in the CSS for the hide.
- Remove float:right from the span. text-align:center won't have any effect unless you remove the float css property.
- I've added the class largeScreen as the classes `col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3` will make the width of the div to 25% and not full width of the screen.

Hope this answer helps you solve your problem.

Comment: when i edited my above code as you said it is hiding all the data except the client area. i want to hide them as i resize the window

Answer (score 0):

```css
.codrops-top {
        line-height: 30px;
        font-size: 13px;
        background: #fff;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
        text-transform: uppercase;
        z-index: 9999;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        font-family: Cambria, Georgia, serif;
        box-shadow: 1px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        font-weight: 900;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .codrops-top a {
        padding: 0px 10px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        color: #333;
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .codrops-top a:hover {
        color:#12836d;
        cursor:pointer;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .codrops-top a{
        color:black;
    }
    .fa{
        padding:0 5px;
    }
    .codrops-top span a.btn {
        padding: 9px 38px;
        line-height: 20px;
    }
    .codrops-top span a.btn-primary {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #5bbc2e;
        border-color: #5bbc2e;
    }
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
        .codrops-top{
            text-align: center;
        }
        .codrops-top span.right{
            text-align: center;
            float:none;

        }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1338px){
        #hide{display:none;             
        }
        .codrops-top{
           text-align: center;
           float:right;
       }
   }
```

```html
<div class="codrops-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div id="hide" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                        <a href="">
                            <strong>Your Tech Friend </strong><span><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i></span>+91-8510-808-808
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="hide" style="text-align:center;" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <a href="">
                            <strong><span><i class="fa fa-book"></i></span>Blog</strong>
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                            <strong><span><i class="fa fa-trophy"></i></span>Career</strong>
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                            <strong><span><i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i></span>Site Map</strong>
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                            <strong><span><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i></span>Request a Quote</strong>
                        </a>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                        <span class="right">
                            <a href="">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Client Area</a>
                            </a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Check with this demo.

Comment: no not working the button is going to the left i want it in fixed center (:

Comment: What you need.. Is it fine in demo link.